# Water coming in, don't know where from

Tags: water, waterproofing

I have been struggling with a water leak in a flex space I have.

I don't know where it is coming from. I have removed the bottom siding panel, the paper behind and the wood is dry, but the concrete is very wet. I live in Vancouver and it rains a lot here. At first I thought it was coming underneath the siding from capillary action, but now I am inclined to think the concrete itself is the suspect. Thoughts?

How can I fix this? Tar? waterproof paint? Do you guys think it is the concrete or something else? Only the baseboards and floor on the sides are wet inside.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of what is above that corner on the exterior? It looks like the concrete is far more wet on that corner that just a few feet over (first pic). It might by puddling, but it doesn't really look like it to me. I'm thinking maybe a leak running down that corner on the exterior.

Comment: It's because the dry part is undercover. Any side that is exposed to rain is facing the same problem. Basically 3 sides of the space are exposed to rain, and the 1 side is not.

Comment: I think a picture from above that outside corner would still be helpful. Also, a picture of the inside with the plastic lifted. The first picture: is the right side that outside corner?

Comment: I have updated the post to show the surroundings

Comment: sorry, but I’m having a hard time seeing how those new pics tie into the old ones. Can you plastic/tarp the entire area and see if the water issues go away? That could help to narrow the cause

Comment: Could this be a drainage issue in the surrounding yard? The yard is also always flooding.

Comment: Drainage is important, but if the concrete was wicking the water up, I would expect water damage on that framing behind the tar paper. Full disclaimer: I am not a professional contractor, but I have some experience working on my own properties

Comment: We are thinking it's coming through the concrete. Wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: I think it is a good possibility, but I don’t know of a cheap fix it that is the case. I would think you’d need to trench around the exterior and install a weeping system as well as water proofing the exposed slab if it is the concrete allowing that water/moisture in

Answer (score 2):

the reason is the shape and location of this ledge:[image: a white ledge absolutely unsuitable for use here]

Therefore, take all the ledge off, look for slits (which are taking water inside from all terrace), 
seal them and if need, give on edge some suitable profile you can see here:

https://www.riversidesheetmetal.net/flashing-metal/masonry/custom/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good picture, but it's still not clear what your concern is, what you think needs fixing, and where the new flashing would be.

Comment: Take what ledge off? And out the flashing where?

Comment: The water damage inside looks more like water is getting in around that window or as johny said. It could be the deck flashing doesn't skirt the water to the outside of the wood siding. Was the water coming in before that shed was there? The shed might be the problem if rain bounces off of it and into the window.

Comment: Gutter not wide nor long enough. Bolts from railings probably also leak. If the flashing doesn't go inside the gutter, the *whole thing* definitely leaks.